# Display the latest posts, published in the last hour, with WP_Query

Tags: posts, wp-query

For a custom widget I want to retrieve the last posts published in the last hour.

All I can do actually is to display the posts of the day, with this query  :

```
$queryArgs = array(
    'category_name' => 'myCategory',
    'posts_per_page'=> $number,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => date( 'Y' ),
            'month' => date( 'm' ),
            'day' => date( 'd' )
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($queryArgs);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following to query for last hour posts:

```
'date_query' => [
     [
         'after'     => '1 hour ago',  
         'inclusive' => true,
     ],
 ],
```

or

```
'date_query' => [
     [
         'after'     => 'last hour',  
         'inclusive' => true,
     ],
 ],
```

or

```
'date_query' => [
     [
         'after'     => '-1 hour',  
         'inclusive' => true,
     ],
 ],
```

Here we are playing with the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) support in `date_query`.

Comment: with this arguments wp_query doesn't return any post.

Comment: what's the output of `echo $query->request;` ?

Comment: it works thank you very much . i used '-1 hour'